# Complex scalar field, generating functional?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

The Lagrangian for the complex scalar field is$$\mathcal{L} = \partial_\mu \phi^* \partial^\mu \phi - m^2 \phi^* \phi.$$Can anyone work out or provide me a reference to the computation of the generating functional$$Z[J, J^*] = \int \mathcal{D}\phi \,\exp\left\{i \int d^4x\,[\mathcal{L} + J(x)\phi^*(x) + J^*(x)\phi(x)]\right\}?$$I need this result for my research, but unfortunately, I am not a physicist by training. Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like a QFT homework problem.

Comment: @JeffHarvey ---  it might be --- but since it got a whole bunch of upvotes, I thought I'd answer it to get it out of the "unanswered" queue

Comment: Yes, but I now know for a fact that it *was* a homework problem and I don't think we should be encouraging people to post homework problems here by answering them.

Answer (score 3):

you can find this calculation, for example, in [chapter 7](http://www.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/b6/psfiles/Chapter-6-qurelfld.pdf) of Kleinert's [path integral book](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/6223), I reproduce the relevant equations:

[image]